# Is there a way to check if a socket is still running?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I need to make a chat between two clients. But I don't know when a socket is closed or not, is there a way to check if it is?

Here is the part of the code that I need to fix:

```
def main():
    """Implements the conversation with server."""
    # Open client socket, Transport layer: protocol TCP, Network layer: protocol IP
    client_socket = socket.socket()
    client_socket.connect((HOST_IP, PORT))

    # start conversation with new client in parallel thread
    name = input("enter your name ")
    protocol.send_request(client_socket, name)
    thread_for_responses = threading.Thread(target=get_responses,
                                            args=(client_socket, ))
    thread_for_responses.start()

    while True:
        # Get request from keyboard
        client_request_str = input()
        if client_request_str:  # if client_request_str not empty string
            # send request according to the protocol
            protocol.send_request(client_socket, client_request_str)
            # Get response from server
```

Instead of `while True`, I need to check if the socket is closed so it won't go into a loop where it will crush for using a closed socket.

Comment: Let's say there were such a way and you used it.  What would your guarantee be that the socket *still* wasn't closed by the time the loop iteration got around to using the socket?

Comment: What if the socket is closed between `isAlive()` and `send_request`?

Comment: It is a very small window of time, my chat is only for a school project.

Comment: I would like to make the most accurate if you have a suggestion I will gladly take a look.

Comment: A *socket* is 'running' until you close it. However the *connection* to which it is an endpoint may be dropped, and this is signalled by errors when reading or writing, or end of stream when reading. There is no other test in TCP or UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python programmers usually say it is easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission.  By this they mean "handle the exception".

For example, you cannot divide by zero.  Here are two ways you could deal with this fact:

```
def print_quotient(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        print("quotient is not a number")
    else:
        print("quotient is {}".format(a / b))
```

vs

```
def print_quotient(a, b):
    try:
        print("quotient is {}".format(a / b))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("quotient is not a number")
```

These functions behave the same way so it doesn't make a lot of difference which approach you take.  This is because `b` cannot change.  This differs from your example where the socket *can* change.  External factors influence its state and this changes the behavior of trying to use it (for example, to send bytes with it).  In this case, exception handling is superior because it does not have to try to make sure nothing is going to go wrong, it just handles things when they go wrong.  There is no case where the code thinks it has set everything up to work correctly and then it turns out it has missed something.

So, when you use socket operations, apply exception handling for any exceptions that might arise from those operations.